# Laravel 5.5 Consolidate migrations w/ production database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration, laravel-5.5

Hopefully, I can explain this well.

I have a Laravel application that has been in production for a minute. So, I have a bunch of migration files with a lot of changes. I would like to consolidate these migration files without losing the database.

The way I *think* this would work:

1. Get all production tables migrated to the desired state.
2. Consolidate all the migration files into the minimum number of files needed.
3. Clear the migrations table.
4. Either run migrations or populate the migrations table.

Part of why I would like to do this is because I would like to make some of the service providers public with the cleanest migration set possible.

The difficult version might be to:

1. Backup or duplicate tables.
2. Run migrations.
3. Write and run script to populate the "clean" tables.

Just hoping there's an easier way than that.

Edit (from comments): I have a production database that has about 50+ migration files - some minor changes, some large changes. If I consolidated, the number of migrations needed would be about 12 or so. I would like to consolidate the migration files, but still be able to perform `migrate:rollback` on production - not that I would.

Comment: So, You have db structure quit old and now you have made changes to db and want to update these changes to production as well ?

Comment: take bakup of your database and run `php artisan migrate:refresh` command.

Comment: You could also make migrations that alter the current tables with the desired columns and migrate it.

Comment: I might not be fully understanding. I have a *production* database that has about 50+ migration files - some minor changes, some large changes. If I consolidated, the number of migrations needed would be more like 12 or so. I would like to consolidate the migration files, but still be able to perform `migrate:rollback` on production - not that I would.

Comment: That's going to take a bit of work, since you wouldn't want to remove the data from a live database. Consolidate your files, then remove the deleted migration files from the migrations table.

Comment: @aynber: Agreed. Would I then be able to add the migration records by hand and be able to rollback? Maybe it would be easier to export, drop, migrate, import...concern there is a possible regression on foreign keys.

Comment: You can, or just add the rollback to the `drop` function of your existing migrations.

Comment: @JoshBruce Did I misunderstand the question in my answer? Are you trying to update your current database without having to rollback to achieve it?

Comment: @Classified: Yeah, it was misunderstood. I'm able to build *more* migrations without a problem. But, before I make some of these services public for use by others, I want to clean it up while maintaining my production data and using the same codebase. See updated question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a couple of over-engineered and overly clever solution attempts, I think the following is a workable solution to the problem.

tl;dr:

- Bookend migrations on either side of migration(s) that build the schema from nothing.
- Update project.
- Migrate.
- Delete bookends and all previous migrations.
- Delete records from `migrations` table.

The first bookend renames the affected tables. The second bookend copies the data from the renamed tables to the fresh tables, then deletes the renamed tables.

*Note: You can do whatever you like inside the bookends, this is just a minimum.*

So, let's say you something like the following for migrations:

- 2017_09_05_000000_create_some_table.php
- 2017_09_05_000001_add_field_x_to_some_table.php
- 2017_09_05_000002_add_field_y_to_some_table.php
- 2017_09_05_000003_add_field_z_to_some_table.php

We would create another migration:

- 2017_09_05_000004_pre_refresh.php

We would create another migration based on the knowledge we have now:

- 2017_09_05_000005_create_some_table.php

We would create the last bookend, where data migration will occur:

- 2017_09_05_000006_post_refresh.php

The first four migrations will not be run because they already have been.

```php
/** 2017_09_05_000004_pre_refresh.php */
class PreRefresh extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $prefix = 'zz_';
        $tablesToRename = [
            'foos',
            'bars'
        ];

        foreach($tablesToRename as $table) {
            Schema::rename($table, $prefix . $table);
        }
    }
}
```

No need for a down, because this is a one shot deal. This will run first, which should result in all the tables listed in the array being renamed. Then the consolidated (optimized) migration(s) will run.

```php
/** 2017_09_05_000006_post_refresh.php */
class PostRefresh extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        // Do what you need to do.
        // If you cannot use your models, just use DB::table() commands.

        $foos = DB::table('zz_foos')->get();
        foreach ($foos as $foo) {
            DB::table('foo')->insert([
                    'id'         => $foo->id,
                    'created_at' => $foo->created_at,
                    'updated_at' => $foo->updated_at
                ]);
        }

        $bars = DB::table('zz_bars')->get();
        foreach ($bars as $bar) {
            DB::table('bar')->insert([
                    'id'         => $bar->id,
                    'created_at' => $bar->created_at,
                    'updated_at' => $bar->updated_at,
                    'foo_id'     => $bar->foo_id
                ]);
        }

        // Tear down.
        $prefix = 'zz_';
        $tablesToRename = [
            'foo',
            'bar'
        ];

        foreach ($tablesToRename as $table) {
            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
            Schema::dropIfExists($prefix . $table);
            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
        }
    }
}
```

After running this, you can delete all your migrations from the `pre_refresh` and prior. As well as the `post_refresh`. Then you can head into the `migrations` table and delete the entries for those migrations.

Deleting the entries isn't entirely necessary, but if you `migrate:rollback` you will get error messages stating that the migration can't be found.

### Caveats

1. If the architecture isn't modular by design, it can be quite cumbersome. However, if you have separated your code into services it does appear to be a little easier.
2. Laravel error handling and messages during migrations are very limited; so, debugging could be difficult.
3. Highly recommend starting with the most stable tables in your app/service. Further, starting with those that are foundational to your app might also prove beneficial.

Note: When I actually do this in production, not just my local (over and over again), and if there is not a better answer, then I will accept this.

### Considerations

If you are breaking your application into service providers with discreet migrations, then you can comment out the service provider in `/config/app` when you run the migrations. This way you create a batch for the now baselined service. So, let's say you have the following migrations where each letter represents a migration, and each duplicate letter represents the same service:

- A
- B
- C
- A
- C
- B
- A

After consolidating service A:

- B
- C
- C
- B
- A

After consolidating B:

- C
- C
- A
- B

After consolidating C:

- A
- B
- C

**update**

54 migrations down to 27 so far. I even pulled out some Schema changes from large `up()` and `down()` methods and make them separate migrations. The nice side-effect here is the batches. I migrated starting with the base tables upon which everything else is supported; therefore, rolling back is more service by service.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the library "`xethron/migrations-generator`" . Here's the [repo](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator).

After installation, basic usage:
`php artisan migrate:generate`

Some Discussions about this are found [at laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-migrations-from-existing-database).

Comment: Or https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator which supports Laravel 8

Answer (score 2):

I found this question, while looking for the information on combining (laravel calls it squashing) migrations. I figured I'd drop an answer, for anyone looking for this information in the future.

Laravel 8.0 allows this now:

`./artisan schema:dump` while use your database cli client to export a database schema dump into the database/schema folder of laravel.

future calls to `./artisan migrate` will execute the schema file first if no migrations have been run on the target database, then it will pick up and run all migrations after the last one that was stored in the schema dump file.

You can read more here [Laravel 8.0 Squash Database Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#squashing-migrations)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are doing it in wrong way. Normally you shouldn't touch your migrations so there's no point to merge them. Especially if you pushed your code in production server you shouldn't touch at all.

So to sum up - migrations are to help you keeping your database schema as it should be but if you want to play with them, merge them or rebuild, no one will stop you, but if you make mistake, you can break something easily.

There's nothing wrong to have multiple migrations with small changes - this is how it works, you make changes for your PHP files, you make changes in your schema.

Comment: Not sure this "you're doing it wrong" answer is helpful. I know how it is supposed to work; been doing it that way for a couple of years. I would like to make a package available to the developer community...they don't need to know the database architecture changes that led to the latest version. The hurdle is how to do that and maintain the production data, which is the only database with the schema while allowing me to use the same code base I'm offering the community.

Comment: Migrations are used both to move production forward during deploys, but they are also used in two development scenarios: Setting up a seeded local database, and for bootstrapping functional/integration tests.

When you have hundreds or even thousands of migrations, cleanups sadly become necessary. In practice, businesses often run experiments where a table or column only existed temporarily.