# Laravel reduce migration files

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I have a Laravel application that uses a DB. The DB is big and was produced by many migration files. Is there a way to cut down the number of migration files so that each table has one migration file? Also Would something results from having too many migration files? like performance issues?

Answer (score 4):

if you have **laravel 8** you can use `squashing-migrations`

by run `php artisan schema:dump` cmd

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#squashing-migrations

for older version you can try this

https://github.com/Cytracom/laravel-migration-squasher

or you can try this
[Laravel 5.5 Consolidate migrations w/ production database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056078/laravel-5-5-consolidate-migrations-w-production-database)

Comment: No sadly, it is 5.7

Answer (score 1):

after laravel 8 you can run `php artisan schema:dump`

it change all migrations to single schema file
For more explanation check link https://advancedwebtuts.com/tutorial/what-is-the-use-of-laravel-squashing-migrations-schema-dump-command

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31948101)

Comment: Im not really sure what more he can add to his answer? Theres not really a lot to explain?